Как сделать бота приложением в discord python
Как сделать так чтобы дискорд сам помогал дополнять команды типа как тут

Типа надо как-то подтвердить бота?


Как сделать так чтобы дискорд сам помогал дополнять команды типа как тут?

Писать бота на основе slash-команд:
from discord.app_commands import CommandTree, describe
from discord import Interaction, Object, Client, Intents

class Bot(Client):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        Client.__init__(self, intents=Intents.all())
        GUILD_ID: int = ----------------------
        self.tree: CommandTree = CommandTree(self)
        self.guild_object: Object = Object(id=GUILD_ID)
        
        @self.tree.command(name="команда", description="Ваша первая команда", guild=self.guild_object)
        @describe(text="Просто текст")
        async def команда(interaction: Interaction, text: str):
            await interaction.response.send_message(text if text else "text не указан", ephemeral=True)

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        await self.tree.sync(guild=self.guild_object)


bot = Bot()
bot.run(token=token, reconnect=True)

Насчёт "Добавить приложение" и "Опробуйте мои команды" в профиле бота я хз, но скорее всего его нужно отправить на проверку.
